# Wildfly Domain TimeoutException with ServiceActivators

Tags: cluster-computing, wildfly-8, infinispan, jgroups

In a AWS domain environment with 2 hosts and one server-group "main-server-group" HOST 1 has only one AS called server-one, HOST 2 has one AS called server-two. The domain.xml file uses standard infinispan configurations and TCPPING instead of MPING (multicast is not enabled).

I have an exception when both hosts starts simultaneously:

HOST 1

```
2016-06-07 10:43:39,455 ERROR [org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000260: Exception executing command: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for topology 1
```

HOST 2

```
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,045 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 0 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,045 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 1 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,045 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 2 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,045 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 3 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,045 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 4 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,045 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 5 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,046 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 6 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,046 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 7 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,046 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 8 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,046 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 9 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,046 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 10 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,046 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 11 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,047 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 12 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,040 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.infinispan.server.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.server.default: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete() throws java.lang.InterruptedException on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,047 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 13 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,047 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 14 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,047 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 15 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,047 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 17 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,048 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 16 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,048 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 19 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,048 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 18 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,048 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 21 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,048 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 20 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,048 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 23 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,048 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 22 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,049 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 25 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,049 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 24 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,049 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 27 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,049 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 26 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,049 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 29 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,059 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 28 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,059 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 31 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,059 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 30 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,059 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 34 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,059 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 35 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,059 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 32 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,060 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 33 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,060 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 38 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,060 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 39 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,060 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 36 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,060 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 37 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,060 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 42 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,061 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 43 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,061 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 40 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,061 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 41 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,061 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 46 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,061 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 47 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,061 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 44 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,062 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 45 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,062 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 51 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,062 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 50 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,062 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 49 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,062 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 48 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,062 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 55 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,063 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 54 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,063 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 53 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,063 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 52 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,063 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 59 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,063 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 58 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,063 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 57 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,064 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 56 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,064 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 0 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,064 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 1 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,064 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 2 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,064 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 3 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,064 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 4 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,064 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 5 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,065 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 6 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,065 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 7 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,065 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 8 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,065 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 9 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,065 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 10 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,065 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 11 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,066 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 12 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,066 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 13 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,066 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 14 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,066 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 15 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,066 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 17 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,066 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 16 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,067 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 19 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,067 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 18 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,067 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 21 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
    2016-06-07 10:43:39,067 ERROR [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (remote-thread-0) ISPN000208: No live owners found for segment 20 of cache default. Current owners are:  [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]. Faulty owners: [<HOST 1>:server-one/server]
        2016-06-07 10:43:39,067 ERROR 
...
```

And the deployment fails in the domain.

Starting HOST 1 and after it has deployed starting HOST 2 doesn't throw any exception. Removing the code where I use ServiceActivator also doesn't throw any exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the tag `<state-transfer timeout="600000"/>` to the cache "default" of cache-container "server". That allowed the Service Activators to correctly deploy.

Answer (score 2):

Just a hint - there is a [AWS Ping Protocol for JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/index.html#_aws_ping).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give that a try :)